# Отправка данных node.js

Tags: node.js

Пишу отправку данных на node.js но скрипт не отрабатывает, тут что-то типо ajax, помогите разобраться

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
    current_product_articl: current_product_articl,
    current_product_site: current_product_site,
    current_product_price: current_product_price
})


const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 443,
    path: 'http://localhost/site_name/php/update.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d)
        console.log(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
})

// console.log(`DATA: ${data}`)
req.write(data)
req.end()
```

***Пробовал отправить через AXIOS***

```
const axios = require('axios')

axios
    .post('http://localhost/site_name/php/update.php', {
        current_product_articl: current_product_articl,
        current_product_site: current_product_site,
        current_product_price: current_product_price
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
```

***Вот что возвращает консоль***

```
statusCode: undefined
{ status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers:
   { date: 'Wed, 23 Dec 2020 12:24:21 GMT',
     server:
      'Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0',
     'x-powered-by': 'PHP/7.4.12',
     'content-length': '23',
     connection: 'close',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' },
  config:
   { url: 'http://localhost/site_name/php/update.php',
     method: 'post',
     data:
      '{"current_product_articl":"AT0118","current_product_site":"links_wb","current_product_price":"Не указано на сайте"}',
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
        'Content-Length': 131 },
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 0,
     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     maxBodyLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus] },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        connect: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 7,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 3237,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 3237,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     _header:
      'POST /site_name/php/update.php HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\nContent-Length: 131\r\nHost: localhost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256 },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
     path: '/site_name/php/update.php',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Socket],
        connection: [Socket],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        client: [Socket],
        _consuming: false,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'http://localhost/site_name/php/update.php',
        redirects: [] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _ended: true,
        _ending: true,
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 131,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'http://localhost/site_name/php/update.php' },
     [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        'content-length': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  data: 'Not all params are set ' }
```

Comment: а "скрипт", когда "не отрабатывает", что-то сообщает вам? какую-то информацию про ошибки?

Comment: Ошибок никаких нет, скрипт не останавливается просто выполняется код дальше

Comment: тогда вы что-то умалчиваете в вопросе. запустив ваш скрипт обязательно получишь ошибку `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Да действительно, там не синтакс эрор там файлика нет запрашиваемого на стороне php

Comment: и плюс Not all params are set

Comment: если решение не связано с кодом, приведённом в этом вопросе, вопрос лучше удалить

Comment: Переделал скрипт, это на стороне PHP была ошибка, сейчас вопрос сертификат эрорс
{ Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1058:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:636:8) code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED' }

Comment: вам нужно обновить сертификат. или сообщить nodejs, что вам всё равно `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';`

Comment: Переделал немного вопрос, так как я отсылал гет а получал пост, сейчас все правильно, но не отправляется DATA, что тут может быть не правильно ?

Comment: здесь смешаны http и https, возможно, причина в этом `require('https')`, `port: 443`, `path: 'http://localhost`

Comment: Переделал https на http

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bad request!</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:you@example.com" />
<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    a:link { color: #0000CC; }
    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
    span {font-size: smaller;}
/*]]>*/--></style>
</head>

Comment: axios вам сообщает ответ сервера `data: 'Not all params are set '`

Comment: а что этот тогда? {"current_product_articl":"AT0118","current_product_site":"links_wb","current_product_price":"Не указано на сайте"}',

Comment: это - параметры, которые не соответствуют ожиданиям бэкенда